# Double insert into a single table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have four percentiles that I wish to insert into a table, but each time I do so individually, it causes the table to stack the values as new rows instead of putting the columns together in the same rows. What I have so far in terms of code.

```
WITH PERCENTILES AS (SELECT TMC_code, EPOCH, percentile_CONT(.95)  
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cast(travel_time_minutes as float)) OVER (PARTITION BY TMC_code) AS P95morning, percentile_CONT(.50)  
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cast(travel_time_minutes as float)) OVER (PARTITION BY TMC_code) AS P50morning   FROM [dbo].[AR_2018_TRUCKS_1_3]
WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, EPOCH) between 7 and 8  AND (WKDAY != 'SAT' and WKDAY != 'SUN'))

insert tmcfour (p95morning, p50morning) select p95morning, p50morning from percentiles GROUP BY TMC_code, P95morning, p50morning ORDER BY TMC_CODE

go 

WITH PERCENTILES_Afternoon AS (SELECT TMC_code, EPOCH, percentile_CONT(.95)  
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cast(travel_time_minutes as float)) OVER (PARTITION BY TMC_code) AS P95afternoon, percentile_CONT(.50)  
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cast(travel_time_minutes as float)) OVER (PARTITION BY TMC_code) AS P50afternoon  FROM [dbo].[AR_2018_TRUCKS_1_3]
WHERE DATEPART(HOUR, EPOCH) between 16 and 17  AND (WKDAY != 'SAT' and WKDAY != 'SUN'))



insert tmcfour (p95afternoon, p50afternoon) select p95afternoon, p50afternoon from percentiles_afternoon GROUP BY TMC_code, P95afternoon, p50afternoon ORDER BY TMC_CODE
```

Comment: This is the third question on this same topic in two days. The problem is still the same. An INSERT statement adds a new row to a table. You want to use one insert and then an update.

Comment: How do you then use an update statement with a with function? All the examples I can find on the internet don't explain this.

Comment: With is not a function. It is merely syntactical sugar for a derived query or an inline table. As requested in your other posts can you please provide the table structure? Your insert statements are only inserting calculated data but nothing to indicate what row it belongs to. I suspect that TMC_code is the primary key? Of course you aren't inserting into that column but it is in your select statements. With a [mcve] this would take literally a few minutes to provide a solution.

Comment: Tmc_Code, P95_afternoon, P50_Afternoon, P95_Morning, P50_Morning. TMC not a primary key as the source table has 361 million records that I am trying to reduce down to 3440. Each TMC has multiple values to it that I can pair down to one row per TMC with percentiles and group by. I've been trying to get these percentiles to aggregate into the same table, as so far I've managed it with the morning and afternoon but not together at the same time.

Comment: Here is the problem. I can't see your screen, I don't know your tables and I don't know what you are trying to do. from what you have posted there is no way to know that row X from the first query is row X in the second query. You really need to post ddl (create table statements) and sample data (insert statements) in addition to what you expect. This just isn't that difficult when you provide all the details needed.